# The difference between ListedColormap and LinearSegmentedColormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I print two similar commands of matplotlib colormaps, as shown below

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, ListedColormap
print(mpl.colormaps['viridis'].resampled(100))
print(mpl.colormaps['copper'].resampled(100))
```

The first result is `ListedColormap`  object and the second result is `LinearSegmentedColormap` .

I know there are quite few differences between these two objects, but I can't make clear why it gives the different kinds of objects.

Could anyone explain that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mpl.colormaps['viridis'] returns a ListedColormap object: viridis is a predefined colormap in Matplotlib that is stored as a ListedColormap. A ListedColormap is essentially a list of colors that define the colormap. This means that it's a discrete colormap with a predefined set of colors, and it doesn't interpolate between colors. When you resample it, you get another ListedColormap object.

mpl.colormaps['copper'] returns a LinearSegmentedColormap object: copper is another predefined colormap in Matplotlib, but it is stored as a LinearSegmentedColormap. A LinearSegmentedColormap is a continuous colormap that can be defined with a set of control points, allowing for interpolation between colors. When you resample it, you also get a LinearSegmentedColormap object.

So, the difference in the type of object returned is due to how these colormaps are originally defined. viridis is discrete, while copper is continuous. When you resample them, they retain their original characteristics, resulting in different types of colormap objects.

Comment: Thanks for the very nice answer!!! An additional question: do you know where I can get the information about the type of colormap, i.e., the colormap is discrete or continuous?

Answer (score 1):

They are obviously two different colormaps.

**viridis** is part of the perceptually uniform colormaps. It is defined as a [listedColormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html), which means its just a list of colors for values.

**copper** on the other hand is sequential and defined as [LinearSegmentedColormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html) that allows smooth transitions between colors and can be defined using a set of control points

But why is that a problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm just unclear for which cmap, I will get a  ListedColormap, and for which kind of cmaps, I will get a LinearSegmentedColormap. Do you know that?

Comment: It depends on the colormap. when the goal is to have distinct colors for different data values its defined as ListedColormap, when you need a more continous colormap with smoother transition, LinearSegmentedColormap is used. But you use it the same way.